# how to add a text in particular line using Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to add "<?xml-stylesheet href="view.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>" this line in below xml file after the "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>". Kindly check and provide the correct batch program.

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="view.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!--s1.dtd v4.20-->
<!DOCTYPE article_set SYSTEM "s1.dtd">
```

Comment: What have you written so far ?   Show us your research and effort attempted please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's a gimme-tha-codez question

Comment: did you search in stackoverflow before posting this question ? this posts may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Comment: So you basically want to insert a line of text after the first line in the file, right?

Comment: yes sir. i want to insert a line of text after the first line in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Before I start, let me recommend you to use another language that is capable of treating XML data as XML data natively; treating them as "normal" text data may damage the XML data structure.

Anyway, to insert a line of text into a file after the first line, you could use the following code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SECOND=<?xml-stylesheet href="view.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>"
< "datafile.xml" > "datafile.xml.tmp" (
    set /P FIRST=""
    echo(!FIRST!
    echo(!SECOND!
    findstr "^"
)
> nul move /Y "datafile.xml.tmp" "datafile.xml"
endlocal
```

Limitations: the text data must be ANSI-encoded; the first line must not be longer than 1023 bytes (including the trailing line-break); the remaining lines must not be longer than 8192 bytes (also including the trailing line-break); the script does not check the content of the file, it simply inserts a line after the first one.

Next time when asking a question, please show some own efforts to solve the problem...